# Why can't I move the first Desktop in Mission control?

Tags: spaces

All spaces are moveable between each other except the first. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first desktop is considered the master all of others (more like the one ring of Lord of the rings ... One ring to rule them all) ...
For example, if you try changing the background on one of your desktops, it will only change for this one. Except the first one will change the background of all your desktops.

Comment: Thanks! Just think it isn't user-friendly at all, especially coming from Apple.

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered a solution, at least for 10.9.3.

Enable the option "Displays have separate Spaces" in "System Preferences" -> "Mission Control". This make it possible to move all Desktops, including Dashboard as shown in George Garside animation above.

I think this makes the accepted answer (at least partly) incorrect.

Comment: This also works in 10.10.5.

Answer (score 0):

*Whilst this might not answer the 'why'…*

Moving the first desktop in Mission Control is at least possible in Mavericks.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! May I ask how you made the animated gif?

Answer (score 0):

This was possible in 10.9, but it seems to have been disabled in 10.9.1

Comment: Yes, it seems to be broken indeed on 10.9.1